# How to access the variable of process P2 through pointer of process P1.?

Tags: memory-management, operating-system

There are two processes. One process(process P1) has a pointer to a variable in the other process(process P2). Now, i want to access the variable of process P2 through pointer of process P1.

This can be done by using shared memory.

How shared memory can be used to access the variable? Should i also consider the memory mapping of the two processes?

Is there any alternate way of doing the same?

Comment: Take a look at IPC (Inter Process Communication). There are some pointers to your questions answer there.

Comment: You cannot access virtual memory of another process without some hacks. Further discussion depends on your platform.  I know how to do such trick on Windows.

Comment: If you are doing with *nix then this tutorial may help you. [beejs guide to IPC](http://beej.us/guide/bgipc/output/html/multipage/index.html)